# Strange behavior from a TCP client (FIN ACK followed by SYN request from client)

Tags: tcp, server, signals

I have a strange problem here. I am writing a small server application in C++ on a Raspberry, and a commercial program running on Android is meant to connect to it. The data exchanged are very small packages for position control of a technical device. My program works fine, I set up a standard TCP/IP socket, bind it to an address, start listening and when a SYN signal comes from the client, i accept it. Then the client sends request, I send answers, and all potential error messages and socket errors are of course monitored. The communication from client to server looks like this with other programs using the same protocol (and everything works fine):

Client > SYN

SYN ACK < Server

Client > ACK

Client PSH ACK ... some request ...

ACK < Server

PSH ACK ... some reply ... < Server

and so on. This works fine with other programs using the same protocol, but not with the one on an Android 7 tablet. The reason is that the Client on the tablet sends FIN, ACK followed by SYN immediately when receiving the first reply from the server. The client has received the reply and processed it happily without any error - there is no obvious reason for the FIN! That might be a bug, but I do not have access to the client code. Is there a workaround to handle this aside from calling "accept" again after each write from the server???? Many thanks in advance ...

Comment: The FIN tells the server that the client is not going to send more (if any) data to the server. The client will still accept data from the server and process it successfully. It seems like you want a persistent connection for multiple commands, right?

Comment: true. the client also expects more data to be processed. as a matter of fact, the SYN request from the client comes 1.3 ms later ... but the server is not set up for accepting that new request. my solution is to setup the sockets with SO_REUSEADDR and SO_LINGER with 0s, shutdown and close the socket after replying and starting another accept to handle the SYN from the client - not very elegant ...

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you control the behavior of the client and the server? A client should be allowed to connect to a sever multiple times in a short period. What limits the frequency is the number of free ports and the time they are marked as unusable.

Comment: No, I don't control the client. The client is supposed to send and receive data over one given port continuously once a connection is established. I think this is a bug in the client.

Comment: We can presume that is a bug. Can take a look at traces if you upload them (tcpdump)

Comment: hi! sorry, i was abroad for a few days - here is a screenshot from wireshark: https://ibb.co/eds5OL  ... 192.168.4.12 is the client.steps1&2 is connection, step 4 is a request from the client, step 6 is the reply from the server. step 8 is a FIN from the client, followed by a request for reconnection after ~ 1 ms ...

Comment: Hi! I have now implemented a shutdown after each write to the client, with a call to a non-blocking accept and a timer. this works fine and makes sure that the reading socket is always closed on both sides. immediate shutdown can be achieve by activating SO_LINGER with a timeout of zero seconds.